# AJAX request from one subdomain to another subdomain, but on the same domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I know that you can't do cross-domain ajax requests unless you use a 'proxy' one server.

However, if I did an ajax request from server1.example.com to server2.example, would that not work, even though it's on the same domain of example.com?

I'm pretty sure sites such as YouTube do ajax requests to different servers. such as a request from youtube.com to vs1022.youtube.com etc.

Any clarification on this would be superb. Thank you for your time.

Comment: see: http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`server1.example.com` and `server2.example.com` considered as cross domain for AJAX request.

You would need to set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` at server side.

Comment: it's really as simple as that? Excellent, but, i'm curious, why doesn't everyone just do that and not have the hassle of creating proxies etc.? :-)

Comment: Basically simple yes, you could read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control, why not allowed by default would be security reasons and policies. For example, if allowed, `server1.example.com` can load all the data from `server2.example.com` with ajax real-time and then very good phishing can be done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header should be formed with set of whitelist maintained by web service provider, unless web services validate requests using auth tokens.