# Why does the browser see requests made from one localhost subdomain to another on the same domain as `sec-fetch-site:cross-site`?

Tags: fetch-metadata, resource-isolation

I have a dockerised local dev env for an SPA. The setup is that there are front-end and back-end subdomains on localhost, running over https.

I.e.:

- fe.localhost
- be.localhost

(These are the actual domains I'm using; they are not placeholders nor obfuscated examples.)

According to the MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site#directives) -

```
same-site

The request initiator and the server hosting the resource have the same scheme, domain and/or subdomain, but not necessarily the same port.
```

Why then are requests from the front-end to the back-end being reported by the browser as `cross-site`?

This happens when e.g. my front-end (which is browsable on `https://fe.localhost` makes a GET or POST request to the back-end on `https://be.localhost/api/people/login`.

Here's the full server code:

```
<?php

include('debugTools.php');
global $data;
$data = [];
function loggedOut() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return [
        'login' => [
            'valid' => false, 
            'message' => 'Not currently logged in.'
        ]
    ];
}
    
function login() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    session_start();
    return [
        'login' => [
            'valid' => true, 
        ]
    ];
}
function loggedIn() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return [
        'login' => [
            'valid' => true, 
        ]
    ];
}

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];


switch($method) {
    case 'POST':
        switch ($path) {
            case '/api/people/login':
                $data = login();
                break;
        }
        break;
    default: // GET
    switch ($path) {
        case '/api/people/login':
            if(session_id()) {
                $data = loggedIn();
            } else {
                $data = loggedOut();
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2101551/2448430 which suggests that sub-domain is considered `cross-site` for AJAX requests. It would be nice to have a link to where that is specified.

Comment: The mention of "domain and/or subdomain" in that doc is a little confusing, and perhaps needs expanding or cross-referencing to a formal definition. It seems obvious that "example.com" and "stackoverflow.com" should not be treated as subdomains of "com", but distinguishing that from the case of "foo.example.com" and "bar.example.com" is actually difficult to do systematically, and requires a "public suffix list".

Comment: Actually for the purpose of the Sec-Fetch request headers, the browser should be treating the domain and subdomain as `same-site` — not as `cross-site`. Notably, they would not be `same-origin` — because for a domain and subdomain, the host part is different. And as far as https://stackoverflow.com/a/2101551/2448430, that’s really not related at all to the Sec-Fetch request-header behavior.

Comment: The spec at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-fetch-metadata/#sec-fetch-site-header does define the relevant behavior here clearly, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site#directives documents what that spec defines. So if you have a domain and subdomain that the browser is not treating as `same-site`, then for anybody else here to help figure out why, we’d need to know the actual exact URLs for the domain and subdomain. Otherwise all we can do is make guesses.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have provided those already in the question: `fe.localhost` and `be.localhost`. The URL on the back-end that is being called by the front-end is `https://be.localhost/api/people/login`

Comment: And as far as using the public suffix list to determine whether or not one domain is a subdomain of another, that’s actually not difficult to do systematically — not for browsers at least. Browsers all do it in exactly the same way, following exactly the same algorithm, which depends on evaluating the host’s “registrable domain”, as defined at https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-registrable-domain.

Comment: Ah OK, yeah, because `localhost` is not a registrable domain, then `fe.localhost` and `be.localhost` are not same-site. And in general for any two URLs whose host parts are not registrable domains and not same-origin, then browsers — per the relevant spec requirements — cannot treat them as same-site but must instead treat them as cross-site.